# How to calculate retention in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, go, elasticsearch, kibana

I got a request that calculate user's retention in elasticsearch.
In my project, I storage user infomation in one index call `user`
How to calculate this metric?
For example, I have one index which mappings is

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "create_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "deleted": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "update_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "username": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "uuid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

`create_time` means user register time and `update_time` means user last login time  and `username` means user unique identification.

For example , I insert rows of data

```
{"index":{"_index":"user","_type":"logs"}}
{"username":"1","create_time":"2015-12-23T12:00:00Z","update_time":"2015-12-24T12:00:00Z"}
{"index":{"_index":"user","_type":"logs"}}
{"username":"2","create_time":"2015-12-23T12:00:00Z","update_time":"2015-12-23T12:00:00Z"}
```

I wanna calculate 23rd retention and its `retention rate of the next day` formula is `The number of users logged in on next day after registration divided by the number of users registered on the 23rd`.

Of course, 23rd rate is `1/2=50%`

Now I can calculate the retention rate for a specified days

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "new_users" : {

      "filters" : {
        "filters" : [
          {
            "range" : {
              "create_time" : {
                "gte" : "2015-12-23",
                "lt" : "2015-12-24"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "register_count" : {
          "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "username"
          }
        },
        "today" : {
          "filter" : {
            "range" : {
              "update_time" : {
                "gte" : "2015-12-24",
                "lt" : "2015-12-25"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs" : {
            "login_count" : {
              "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "username"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "retention" : {
          "bucket_script" : {
            "buckets_path" : {
              "today_count" : "today>login_count",
              "yesterday_count" : "register_count"
            },
            "script" : {
              "lang" : "expression",
              "inline" : "today_count / yesterday_count"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I wanna calculate automatically nearly a month, I dont know how to revise my code upper, thanks your  help!

Comment: revise code upper how to calculate auto nearly a month, I dont know  wanna

Comment: Automatically calculate retention rate by day, someone registered in 23rd and he login on 24rd, saving the total number of registered on 23rd in var `23rd_register_count` and calculate the number of users registered on the 23rd and logged in on the 24th in var `24rd_login_count`, and the 23rd retention is `23rd_register_count / 24rd_login_count`